# Pipe zsh auto completion list to file or less

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

> zsh: do you wish to see all 923 possibilities (462 lines)?

Yes please, but in a file or less.

Comment: How would you get feedback from it?  If it just put all of the possibilities in less, you'd have to read through it, exit, then retype your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, that at least would be better than not being able to read some suggestions at all because they are outside of the terminal buffer or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zsh can do this internally. Put this into your `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-prompt   ''
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt ''
```

before

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

(add the latter lines if not already present)

See the [zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles) for details.